# Atom editor: Emmet not working in markdown files

Tags: markdown, atom-editor, emmet

i'm working with atom editor and emmet package but tab expand not working in md files, the point is that i know how to make emmet work on any format (e.g. .php files) but the method i use not working for .markdown files, i tried:

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="html php markdown md"]:not([mini])':
    'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

and also :

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="html php source gfm"]:not([mini])':
    'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

first, you should install markdown language using [this package](https://atom.io/packages/language-markdown) on atom because as you can see [here](https://atom.io/packages/file-types) atom editor has not markdown lang by default, then you should change your atom editor `keymap.cson` file like this:

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text md"]:not([mini])':
    'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="html php"]:not([mini])':
    'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```